# Escribir en fila y columnas con bucle

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo que extraer las características de varios audios. Son 13 características las que se extraen en cada audio, cada una se guarda en una columna (llamada `mfccs_mean` + número del 1 al 13) de un dataframe llamado `Frame`

Esto lo hace bien para el primer audio, el problema viene cuando quiero hacerlo para varios archivos, me repite los mismo resultados en cada fila.

```
mfccs_df=pd.DataFrame()
index=0

for subdirs, dirs, files in os.walk("prueba"):

    for file in files:

        y, sr = librosa.load((subdirs +"/" + file), res_type='kaiser_fast',duration=3,sr=22050*2,offset=0.5)
        mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr, n_mfcc=13)
        mfccs_mean=np.mean(mfccs,axis=1) 
        print(file)

        for i in range(0,13):

            mfccs_df['mfccs_mean_'+str(i)]=mfccs_mean[i]

        mfccs_df.loc[index]=[mfccs_mean]


        print(mfccs_df.loc[index])
        index += 1
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo? Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué es `Numero`? Si lo he entendido, cada audio generaría una fila nueva que se agrega al final del DataFrame, sin importar en qué directorio o subdirectorio esté ¿No?

Comment: Número es el número total de audios que hay en el directorio "prueba", se guarda previamente su valor. Eso es, cada audio genera una nueva fila que se agrega al final del dataFrame, eso ocurre para todos los audios que haya en los subdirectorios de "prueba". Gracias por el interés!

Comment: El problema es que cuando haces `for file in files:
        for m in range(0, Numero):` por cada audio iteras 5 veces haciendo 5 veces la misma operación. Por eso te preguntaba que es `m` ¿Pruebas contiene solo y exclusivamente los archivos de audio que quieres analizar? En tal caso en principio `for m in range...` no es necesario para nada, para el índice usa un contador o `enumerate` con `files`

Comment: Tienes razón FJSevilla, ya he quitado ese bucle porque no tenía sentido. Ahora estoy con ese código (editado ya) y me sigue haciendo lo mismo, sólo me guarda bien los datos de los dos últimos audios, el resto repite datos y me está volviendo loca. Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Te estás complicando mucho para añadir cada nueva fila. `mfccs_mean` es un array NumPy de 13 elementos, el cual puedes asignar directamente a una fila mediante:

```
mfccs_df.loc[index] = mfccs_mean
```

El código podría quedar así:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import librosa
import numpy as np



N_MFCC = 13
PATH_DIR = "prueba"

cols = [f'mfccs_mean_{i}' for i in range(N_MFCC)]
mfccs_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

index = 0    
for dirpath, _, files in os.walk(PATH_DIR):
    for file in files:
        y, sr = librosa.load(path=os.path.join(dirpath, file),
                             res_type='kaiser_fast',
                             duration=3,
                             sr=22050 * 2,
                             offset=0.5
                             )
        mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr, n_mfcc=N_MFCC)
        mfccs_mean = np.mean(mfccs, axis=1) 
        mfccs_df.loc[index] = mfccs_mean
        index += 1

print(mfccs_df)
```

No es recomendable que generes rutas concatenando cadena manualmente,usa `os.path.join` en su lugar. Es más simple y seguro.

> Si usas Python < 3.6 la linea:
>
> ```
> cols = [f'mfccs_mean_{i}' for i in range(N_MFCC)]
> ```
>
> debe ser:
>
> ```
> cols = ['mfccs_mean_{}'.format(i) for i in range(N_MFCC)]
> ```

No se si es es que no lo precisas, pero tal como construyes el DataFarame no sabes que fila de datos se corresponde con cada archivo de audio (más cuando el orden en que itera `os.walk` es indeterminado). Si necesitas asociarlos, puedes usar la ruta (o el nombre, pero este no tiene por que ser único) como índice o como datos de otra columna.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import librosa
import numpy as np



N_MFCC = 13
PATH_DIR = "prueba"


cols = [f'mfccs_mean_{i}' for i in range(N_MFCC)]
mfccs_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

for dirpath, _, files in os.walk(PATH_DIR):
    for file in files:
        path = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
        y, sr = librosa.load(path=path,
                             res_type='kaiser_fast',
                             duration=3,
                             sr=22050 * 2,
                             offset=0.5
                             )
        mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr, n_mfcc=N_MFCC)
        mfccs_mean = np.mean(mfccs, axis=1) 
        mfccs_df.loc[path] = mfccs_mean
```

Comment: MIL GRACIAS! Así funciona perfectamente.

Comment: @user132361 si la respuesta de FJSevilla te ha servido, debes marcarla como correcta usando el Tick que aparece en el margen superior izquierdo de la respuesta.